# int e Integer - Java

Tags: java, tipagem, objetos, int

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Java e ele está com erro, já o encontrei mas não o compreendo.

```
public class Time{

    private String nome;
    private ArrayList<Jogador> jogadores;
    private Integer gols;

    public void addGol(){
        this.gols = this.gols+1;
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Time time = new Time("A");

        time.addGol();
    }
}
```

Ele está gerando `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`,
A razão é o `private Integer gols;` que está como `Integer`, se eu puser `int` funciona normalmente.

- Alguem sabe dizer o motivo?
- Os dois não são a mesma coisa? sendo `int` primitivo e `Integer`
  objeto?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O valor padrão para um `int`, se você não especificar nenhum, é `0`. O valor padrão para uma referência, seja ela `Integer` ou pra qualquer outra classe, é `null`. Como você nunca especificou o valor inicial de `gols`, ao tentar incrementá-lo ele não consegue - pois a referência é nula.

O ideal é usar `int` mesmo - como `Integer` é **imutável**, ele vai criar uma nova instância cada vez que você fizer alguma operação com ele. Mas caso queira/precise usar `Integer`, dê-lhe um valor inicial e o erro não ocorrerá mais:

```
public class Time{

    private String nome;
    private ArrayList<Jogador> jogadores;
    private Integer gols = 0; // ou new Integer(0), mas com o autoboxing tanto faz
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu, não sabia deste fato.

Answer (score 3):

`Integer` é um classe `Wrapper` que fornece métodos ao `tipo primitivo int` (se quiser conhecer com mais proundidade veja este link [Classes Wrapper](http://www.devmedia.com.br/conhecendo-as-classes-wrappers-autoboxing-e-auto-unboxing/7384)), logo sua propriedade `gols`não é um `tipo primitivo` e sim um objeto `nulo`.