# Como declarar uma variável do tipo inteiro em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, int, tipagem, declaração-de-variável

Estou aprendendo C# para migrar um sistema em VBA para C#. Estou gostando muito da linguagem .NET.

Como que que faço para declarar uma variável do tipo inteiro?

Comment: Olá, Watson William. Fiz uma leve adequação na sua postagem, pois seu nome ja aparece embaixo do texto, e de qualquer forma, ela será lida em vários horários e por várias pessoas. A hora que tiver um tempinho, pode acessar o [Tour], a [Help] e [Ask] para pegar umas dicas e referências para melhor aproveitamento do site. Seja bem-vindo.

Comment: Relacionado, [int e Integer - Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62861/14213), eu sei que é java, mas a semântica é a mesma.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 13):

Basta declarar o tipo antes do nome dela:

```
int x; //declarando sem inicializar. Será inicializado implicitamente com 0
var y = 1; //usando inferência de tipo. Só funciona em variáveis locais
int z = 2; //definição (declaração+atribuição) explícita
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/VarDeclaration.cs).

Os tipos chamados *built-in* da linguagem podem ser vistos [nessa tabela](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Ao contrário do que muitos pensam C# não possuem tipos chamados "primitivos". Estes listados são os que a linguagem provê alguma facilidade extra para seu uso e reconhecimento.

[Sobre os termos usados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101).

[C# é a linguagem, .NET é a plataforma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101).

[Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101)