# Qual a diferença entre Double e double em java?

Tags: java

Estava fazendo um código e, por erro, acabei colocando `double` e a *IDE* aceitou, eu sempre utilizava com o *D* maiúsculo.

Qual a diferença entre os dois?

Comment: Relacionada:[Qual diferença entre Boolean e boolean?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/160914/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [int e Integer - Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62861/28595)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`double` é um tipo de dado primitivo (ou seja, ele não é criado por referência, em outras palavras, não é um objeto). Não sendo um objeto, você não tem acesso a uma série de facilidades que a manipulação de objetos oferece, talvez os mais importantes sendo a conversão de um valor `double` para texto (`String`) e o uso de coleções (`ArrayList`, `Set` etc.), já que estas somente lidam com objetos e não primitivos.

Para tornar possível que tipos primitivos possam fazer uso dos recursos que objetos têm a sua disposição, em Java, para cada tipo primitivo existe uma classe cuja única função é receber o valor dele e "embalar" o valor desse primitivo com um objeto. Essas classes são chamadas de *wrappers* (embaladores). Como em Java, a nomenclatura padrão de classes é primeira letra maiúscula, a classe *wrapper* do primitivo `double` é a `Double`.

Answer (score 11):

A classe `Double` envolve um valor do tipo primitivo `double` em um objeto. Um objeto do tipo `Double` contém um único campo cujo tipo é `double`.

Além disso, essa classe fornece vários métodos para converter um `double` em uma `String` e uma `String` em um `double`, bem como outras constantes e métodos úteis ao lidar com um `double`.

Fonte: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Em resumo, a `classe Double` é um `wrapper`.
Veja mais sobre `Wrappers` [aqui](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3667/classes-wrappers-em-java.aspx).